# symfony2: update data error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

i m trying to update data from database using form.

controller is :

```
public function addAction($id) {

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->find($id);
  if (!$product) {
    $product = new Product();
  }
  $form = $this->createForm(new PageAdd(), $product);
  $request = $this->getRequest();

  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
     $form->bindRequest($request);

     $name=$this->get('request')->request->get('name');
     $price=$this->get('request')->request->get('price');
     $description=$this->get('request')->request->get('description'); 

     if ($form->isValid()) {
        $product->setName($name);
        $product->setPrice($price);
        $product->setDescription($description);    

        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        /*Llamando a la plantilla de listados*/
        $product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->findAll();

        /*Enviando los datos a la plantilla y Renderizandola*/
        return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:pageadd.html.twig', array('Product' => $product));
     }
  }

  return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:show.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'product' => $product));
}
```

and `show.html.twig` file is

```
<form action="{{ path('Product_add',{'id':product.id}) }}"
{{ form_enctype(form) }}>

            {{ form_errors(form) }}

            {{ form_rest(form) }}

               <input type="submit" value="Save This Page" class="savebutton" />

         </form>
```

and its giving me error

> Method "id" for object "Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product" does not exist in AcmeStoreBundle:Default:show.html.twig at line 2
>   500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but in one of your `render()` calls product is with capital 'P', and small in the other.

Answer (score 0):

This means there is a getId() method missing in your product entity .

```
public function getId()
{
  return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: i added this code to my product entity but it still gives me the same error. i think the problem is in show.html.twig.

Comment: Post your getId() code as you probably have a typo based on your error message.  Also, read through the forms section in the manual and follow the basic examples.  There is no reason to pull name/price/description and then set them again.  bindRequest takes care of that.

Comment: I think that you have mixed up the two 'render' lines. The call to show.html.twig should be after persisting the object, and pageadd.html.twig if the form isn't valid